# Record coming sound in Java

Tags: java, audio, record

In my program, i want to record a sound when user say something like Talking Tom Cat, but I only find a way always start recording.
Please, help me. Sorry for my English

Comment: Do you mean that you want to start recording if the user says a specific phrase, for example "Talking Tom Cat"? That is not easy, you would need code that can recognise speech, and that's certainly not built-in into Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to capture and record sound in Java using Sound API

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
* A sample program is to demonstrate how to record sound in Java
* author: www.codejava.net
*/
public class JavaSoundRecorder {
// record duration, in milliseconds
static final long RECORD_TIME = 60000;  // 1 minute

// path of the wav file
File wavFile = new File("E:/Test/RecordAudio.wav");

// format of audio file
AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

// the line from which audio data is captured
TargetDataLine line;

/**
 * Defines an audio format
 */
AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 16000;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 2;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                         channels, signed, bigEndian);
    return format;
}

/**
 * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
 */
void start() {
    try {
        AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        // checks if system supports the data line
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();   // start capturing

        System.out.println("Start capturing...");

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

        System.out.println("Start recording...");

        // start recording
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
 */
void finish() {
    line.stop();
    line.close();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}

/**
 * Entry to run the program
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JavaSoundRecorder recorder = new JavaSoundRecorder();

    // creates a new thread that waits for a specified
    // of time before stopping
    Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder.finish();
        }
    });

    stopper.start();

    // start recording
    recorder.start();
}
}
```

**SOURCE:** http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api